# Create temp table in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a temp table in a stored proc and populate it with values; but it is giving me Invalid object name error

Code:

```
Create procedure sample_proc1
as 
begin
create table #testrproc
(
col1 tinyint
);
insert into #testproc values(1);
select * from #testproc;
end
```

Any pointers on why I am getting this error??

Comment: You have to check name of table properly before posting here.....

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo.  You're creating `#testrproc` not `#testproc`

```
Create procedure sample_proc1
as 
begin
create table #testproc
(
col1 tinyint
);
insert into #testproc values(1);
select * from #testproc;
end
```